# Masking Chapter Title and Number on Chapter Page

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, formatting

I wish to have the 'chapter pages' replaced by an info-graphic of my choosing. The pages that contain the chapter title will all be position on a separate page. The remainder of the chapter content continues on subsequent pages (Works Fine).

The images I intend to use are transparent in nature. Below is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book} 

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage{tikz}    

\begin{document}

\part{First Part}

\chapter{First Chapter}

\thispagestyle{empty} 

\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
\node[opacity=.7,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center){
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]
    {social-media-infographic}};

\clearpage
\newpage

\section{First Section}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\section{Second Section}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

See sample output:

[image: demo of visible through image]

Increasing the opacity to 1 only solves the problems with non-transparent images.

Another idea I had, was to change the font color to white, but if I decide to print on cream paper in the future, it becomes an issue as I no control over the exact shade of cream in which the text will be printed.

**Question**: How do I mask/hide/disable the chapter title and number **only** on the pages in which I intend to put the graphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a chapter where you wish to hide the number and title:

```
...
%\chapter{First Chapter} % the original
\chapter*{{\huge Chapter}} % unnumbered but not in ToC or headers
\refstepcounter{chapter} % increment the chapter number
\chaptermark{First Chapter} % title text for headers
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\thechapter\hspace{0.5em} First Chapter} % put chapter title in the ToC
...
\chapter{Regular Chapter}
...
```

Comment: Your solution is elegant. The bit with the stepcounter and chaptermark eluded me. Thank you.